# how to use .htaccess RewriteRule function to re-format my link

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is like that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And i have a link like that

http://www.site.com/cr?v=lock/223

Does is it possible to use .htaccess RewriteRule to let the link open like that?

http://www.site.com/?l=223
Or
http://www.site.com/l/223

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that your desired format is a valid URL, as I don't think you can have a query string without a filename. Could you use a different target pattern such as www.site.com/l/223 instead?

Comment: yes possible /l/223 is good

Comment: Yes, true..the problem is cr?v=lock/223 have already rewritten before with RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to replace the suggested format (which has a query string on a URL with no filename) with the following instead:

http://www.site.com/l/223

then try the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^l/([0-9]+)$ cr?v=lock/$1
```

If you need to require a three-digit code every time, then use `([0-9]{3})` in the match pattern instead.

Comment: I have updated my Q..could you check it again please..thank you

Comment: Does the RewriteRule in this answer not do what you need? If not, please give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you require any other format.. you can try below link

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

mod_rewrite is the key for the format.